# vue забиндить класс на элемент массива

Tags: vue.js, классы

Ситуация такова: есть массив чисел в 1000 штук. по массиву строится игровое поле 20х50. при клике на ячейку соответствующий элемент массива изменяет значение. css класс ячейки зависит от значения соответствующего элемента массива. как связать класс ячейки с элементом массива, чтобы он динамически отслеживался?  связь типа `:class="{...}"` работает только во время создания компонента, на изменения значения элементов массива не реагирует.

Comment: Добавьте код  ...

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Вопрос решен. https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html
в разделе про массивы подробно описан способ внесения изменений в массив для сохранения реактивности.